# R get values in a row based on another row in in same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe df like this:

df

```
z: a b a a b b b 
y: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I want to get value in y based of the value in z.
For instance I want to a list of numbers from y that have an "a" in z:

```
y: 1 3 4
```

something like `df["y" if z == "a",]`

Thank you!

Comment: `df$y[df$z == 'a']`

Comment: That works if I transpose it first, which isn't an issue. Works for now, thanks!